# Adding different colors with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

This piece of code generate cumulative bar plot like plot below. This is small example of my data set. This set contains weekly data about 52 weeks. You can see data with code below:

```
# CODE
     #Data
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
      ARTIFICIALDATA<-dput(structure(list(week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
        29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
        45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52), `2019 Series_1` = c(534.771929824561, 
        350.385964912281, 644.736842105263, 366.561403508772, 455.649122807018, 
        533.614035087719, 829.964912280702, 466.035087719298, 304.421052631579, 
        549.473684210526, 649.719298245614, 537.964912280702, 484.982456140351, 
        785.929824561404, 576.736842105263, 685.508771929824, 514.842105263158, 
        464.491228070175, 608.245614035088, 756.701754385965, 431.859649122807, 
        524.315789473684, 739.40350877193, 604.736842105263, 669.684210526316, 
        570.491228070175, 641.649122807018, 649.298245614035, 664.210526315789, 
        530.385964912281, 754.315789473684, 646.80701754386, 764.070175438596, 
        421.333333333333, 470.842105263158, 774.245614035088, 752.842105263158, 
        575.368421052632, 538.315789473684, 735.578947368421, 522, 862.561403508772, 
        496.526315789474, 710.631578947368, 584.456140350877, 843.19298245614, 
        563.473684210526, 568.456140350877, 625.368421052632, 768.912280701754, 
        679.824561403509, 642.526315789474), `2020 Series_1` = c(294.350877192983, 
        239.824561403509, 709.614035087719, 569.824561403509, 489.438596491228, 
        561.964912280702, 808.456140350877, 545.157894736842, 589.649122807018, 
        500.877192982456, 584.421052631579, 524.771929824561, 367.438596491228, 
        275.228070175439, 166.736842105263, 58.2456140350878, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
        "data.frame")))
colnames(ARTIFICIALDATA) <- c('week', 'series1', 'series2')

colnames(ARTIFICIALDATA) <- c("week", "series1", "series2")

ARTIFICIALDATA %>%
  # Drop rows with NA 
  drop_na() %>% 
  # Convert to long format
  pivot_longer(-week, names_to = "series") %>%
  # Set the labels for the plot. If you want other lables simply adjust
  mutate(label = case_when(
      series == "series1" ~ "2019 Series_1",
      series == "series2" ~ "2020 Series_1")) %>%  
  # Compute sum by sereis
  group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  # Plot
  plot_ly(x = ~label, y = ~sum) %>% 
  add_bars() %>%
  # Remove title for xaxis. But can you can label it as you like
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""))
```

[image]

But my intention is to have bar plot with two different colors, first bar with blue color like color on example and second with orange color. So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem with colors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `add_bars()` with

```
add_bars(marker = list(color = c("blue", "orange")))
```